# Como depurar una aplicación web de apps script

Tags: script, google-apps-script

Estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar con Apps script de Google, tengo una aplicación que me transfirieron pero no he encontrado la manera de depurar la aplicación publicada en el navegador cuando esta no me carga algunos campos o no funciona. Como puedo ver en el navegador que esta fallando.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para depurar una aplicación web creada usando Google Apps Script debes mirar tanto en la página de ejecuciones del proyecto como en la consola del navegador.

En el nuevo editor, en el panel izquierdo haz clic en Ejecuciones.

En el navegador, abre el URL de tu aplicación web, luego abre las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador y en este la consola.

Para usar el depurador del nuevo editor, primero debes revisar si tu función `doGet` o `doPost` requieren de un objeto evento. Si es así, debes crear una función para inicializar el objeto evento. Luego marca una línea de código como "breakpoint" y haz clic en el botón depurar. Cuando la ejecución llegue al "breackpoint" en el panel de depuración que se mostrará a la derecha podrás ver los valores / objetos de cada variable y en la parte inferior se mostrarán los registros. Podrás pasar a la siguiente línea de código, "saltar", "salir", continuar o detener la ejecución.

Quizás debas agregar `console.log`, agregar `try...catch` a tu código o usar alguna otra técnica. Esto dependerá de tu aplicación, del problema que tenga la aplicación y tus preferencias / habilidades.